# Adding a @property seems to give @implementation of @interface an error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a @interface which i add a property.

```
@interface ITEM : CDVViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverControler * popoverController;
@end
```

when i add the above property, When i clean and build, it gives this error:

```
 Property 'popoverController' attempting to use Ivar '_popoverController' declared in super class 'UIViewController'
```

on this line:

```
@implementation ITEM   //<---
{
...
}
```

I am not quite sure what is going on, but i know it builds correctly when i remove the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to shadow an attribute, the problem is that this attribute already exists the superclass, change the name if you still want to declare it.

**PS**: The convention says that caps should be used for constants, and the class name should begin with an uppercase, so in your case you should change the class name to Item, even though this isn't causing any problem with the compiler.

Comment: You sir, are amazing.  I was looking around, and I couldnt figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Saw the edit.  Yes, i was just doing that for the sake of doing that.  Actual interfaces etc are in proper standard. :)